# Socket: Permission denied for grafana docker

Tags: docker, sockets, permissions, grafana

How repair error of permission socket for docker grafana ?

**docker run**

```
sudo docker run -d --name=grafana -p 3000:3000 grafana/grafana
```

**permission**

```
sudo chown 472:472 /var/run/docker.sock
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
sudo chown 472:472 -R /etc/grafana/
sudo chown 472:472 -R /var/lib/grafana/
sudo chmod 775 -R /etc/grafana/
sudo chown 472:472 -R /var/lib/grafana/
sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER
```

**docker logs**

```
t=2020-06-16T23:03:44+0000 lvl=info msg="Registering plugin" logger=plugins name="Direct Input"
t=2020-06-16T23:03:44+0000 lvl=eror msg="Stopped HTTPServer" logger=server reason="failed to open listener on address 0.0.0.0:3000: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3000: socket: permission denied"
t=2020-06-16T23:03:44+0000 lvl=info msg="Stopped Stream Manager"
t=2020-06-16T23:03:44+0000 lvl=eror msg="A service failed" logger=server err="failed to open listener on address 0.0.0.0:3000: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3000: socket: permission denied"
t=2020-06-16T23:03:44+0000 lvl=eror msg="Server shutdown" logger=server reason="failed to open listener on address 0.0.0.0:3000: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3000: socket: permission denied"
```

Comment: Have you tried to check whether port 3000 is open on your host machine? and also try referring to this [post](https://forums.docker.com/t/failed-to-load-listeners-no-sockets-found-via-socket-activation-make-sure-the-service-was-started-by-systemd/62505/2)